# C# list.Orderby descending

Tags: c#, list, sorting, sql-order-by

I would like to receive a **`List` sorted** by `Product.Name` in **descending order**.

Similar to the function below which sorts the list in ascending order, just in reverse, is this possible?

```
var newList = list.OrderBy(x => x.Product.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I think he meant that it doesn't accept the `descending` keyword, because he didn't begin his expression with `from x in list...`

Comment: Sorry, I did not copy that code exactly, but typed it from memory. My actual code works, but just returns a list that is sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Sure:

```
var newList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Product.Name).ToList();
```

Doc: [OrderByDescending(IEnumerable, Func)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In response to your comment:

```
var newList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Product.Name)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.Product.Price)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: So your edit will sort by name(from z->a) then price (low -> high)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Calls to OrderBy or ThenBy are always ascending. The OrderByDescending and ThenByDescending methods are what you'd use for descending.

Answer (score 26):

Yes. Use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) instead of `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 16):

```
var newList = list.OrderBy(x => x.Product.Name).Reverse()
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 13):

```
list.OrderByDescending();
```

works for me.

Comment: This did nothing without doing list = list.OrderByDescending().toList();

Answer (score 4):

look it this piece of code from my project

I'm trying to re-order the list based on a property inside my model,

```
 allEmployees = new List<Employee>(allEmployees.OrderByDescending(employee => employee.Name));
```

but I faced a problem when a `small and capital letters exist`, so to solve it, I used the string comparer.

```
allEmployees.OrderBy(employee => employee.Name,StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 1):

### 2 options for sorting a List in decending order

**Method 1** Order against a specified key using `OrderByDescending()`

```cs
List<Product> myList = new() {
    new Product("A"),
    new Product("Z"),
    new Product("C")
};
myList = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name).ToList();
Debug.WriteLine(
    $"{myList[0].Name}" + // 'Z'
    $"{myList[1].Name}" + // 'C'
    $"{myList[2].Name}"   // 'A'
);
```

Example Product

```cs
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Product(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

**Method 2** Sort ascending and use Reverse()

```cs
myList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
myList.Reverse();
```

Reverse() is convenient for generic types such as `List<string>`

**Reverse sort a string list**

```cs
List<string> stringList= new() { "A", "Z", "C" };
stringList.Sort();
stringList.Reverse();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
list = new List<ProcedureTime>(); sortedList = list.OrderByDescending(ProcedureTime=> ProcedureTime.EndTime).ToList();
```

Which works for me to show the time sorted in descending order.