# arrange students in descending order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

How can I arrange students in descending order? Here is my code.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mvc; 
using Student.Models;

namespace Student.Controllers {
public class StudentController : Controller

     {
         //
         // GET: /Student/

         private IStudentRepository  _repository;

         public StudentController() : this(new StudentRepository())
         {
         }

         public StudentController(IStudentRepository repository)
         {
             _repository = repository;
         }

         public ActionResult Index()
         {    
              return View(_repository.ListAll());
         } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{    
  return View(_repository.ListAll().OrderByDescending(s => s.Name));
}
```

Replace Name with the property that you wanna order by

**I strongley recommend taking this as an opportunity to look at all the extension methods that linq provide (e.g. OrderBy, Where, Select, .. etc), the more you learn about the linq API the easier your life will get working with Collections**

Comment: +1 bassam, exactly (almost) as i was answering. left mine anyway

Comment: @jim Thanks, I know it happens to me a lot too :D

Comment: @BassamMehanni Thanks for helping. I did try OrderByDescening, but didnt know I needed to pass name in this way. This is the first time I am using a constructor dependency injection. hence got confused.

Answer (score 2):

user793468,

you don't specify the model, so just guessing here:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{    
  return View(_repository.ListAll().OrderByDescending(student => student.Id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list.OrderByDescending(x => x.NameofVariable).ToList();

similar question could be found here
[C# list.Orderby descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925258/c-sharp-list-orderby-descending)