# Sort list on 3 values

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have an List that I want to sort on CategoryCounter, GroupCounter, QuestionCounter all by ascending values.  How can I accomplish this?

```
public class CustomList
{

    private int _categorySequence = 0;
    private int _groupSequence = 0;
    private int _questionSequence = 0;
    private string _name = String.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    } 

    public int CategoryCouter
    {
        get { return _categorySequence; }
        set { _categorySequence = value; }
    }

    public int GroupCounter
    {
        get { return _groupSequence; }
        set { _groupSequence = value; }
    }

    public int QuestionCounter
    {
        get { return _questionSequence; }
        set { _questionSequence = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to use search
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925258/c-sharp-list-orderby-descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) followed by [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx).

```
var result = MyCollection.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryCounter)
                         .ThenBy(y => y.GroupCounter)
                         .ThenBy(z => z.QuestionCounter);
```

Comment: You should use `.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...).ThenBy(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Well... I guess, what you want to do can be done if you:

1. use some sorting algorithm on the first
2. in case of collision, sort by the second
3. in case of collision on the second, sort by the third.

Comment: in c# there are built-in sorting algorithms

Comment: @wudzik: I never claimed there weren't did I? So why the downvote

Comment: not mine downvote, I just posted a clue :)

Comment: @wudzik - only as of certain framework versions, that is an assumption that its 3.5 or later.

Comment: @Steve as far as I know List.Sort is in framework longer than since 3.5 :) according to MSDN since 2.0

Comment: @wudzik - That is correct, however the List.Sort method would not help to sort by properties as asked in the question.